# MySQL Event Schedule every last day of the month

Tags: mysql, sql, events, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule a copy of a table on every last day of the month. But I get an error on code line 4. What should be the correct code? The stored procedure for the table copy works fine.

[image: Screenshot with error]

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `create_table_test_month`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `create_table_test_month`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY LAST_DAY(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) STARTS '2022-03-31 23:30:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
call data.test_create_table();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

With kind regards,

Björn

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the fact that the `EVERY` clause wants an `INTERVAL` type (which identifies the period of time it will lag from the `STARTS` clause), while it's receiving a `DATE` value.

You can solve this issue by feeding an eligible interval in the `EVERY` clause, like the following:

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `create_table_test_month`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `create_table_test_month`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2022-03-31 23:30:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
    call data.test_create_table();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

For more information on events and intervals, there are some good examples at MySQL official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html.

Comment: Hello Lemon,

Will the code EVERY 1 MONTH always select the last day of every month when I choose 2022-03-31?

Comment: Sure. Though you need to make sure that the beginning month has 31 days to make sure MySQL will try to get the 31st of the next month. Here's a sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ee1cee/3.